# Divide a single List of Class Objects into multiple Lists based on Class Members C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by, distinct

I have a Person class that looks like the following:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() { }
    public Person(string name, int age, GenderType gender, string country) { Name = name; Age = age; Gender = gender; Country = country; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public GenderType Gender { get; set; } // GenderType = M/F
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to divide this list into two lists first, based on Gender. Then I want to further divide each list into sub-lists, based on Country. So if I have n-number of distinct countries in the original list, I'd get anywhere from n to 2n number of lists at the end. The following example will further illustrate the idea:

Say my original list is like this:

```
Sam, 23, M, USA
Jon, 13, M, USA
Jen, 26, F, USA
Thilini, 25, F, Sri Lanka
Anna, 23, F, UK
Chelsea, 35, F, UK
Saman, 43, M, Sri Lanka
Dan, 27, M, UK
```

First division:

```
Male lists:
Sam, 23, M, USA
Jon, 13, M, USA
Saman, 43, M, Sri Lanka
Dan, 27, M, UK

------------------

Female lists:
Jen, 26, F, USA
Thilini, 25, F, Sri Lanka
Anna, 23, F, UK
Chelsea, 35, F, UK
```

Then further subdivided lists:

```
Male sub-list 1:
Sam, 23, M, USA
Jon, 13, M, USA

Male sub-list 2:
Saman, 43, M, Sri Lanka

Male sub-list 3:
Dan, 27, M, UK

------------------

Female sub-list 1:
Jen, 26, F, USA

Female sub-list 2:
Thilini, 25, F, Sri Lanka

Female sub-list 3:
Anna, 23, F, UK
Chelsea, 35, F, UK
```

I would easily be able to do this using foreach loops and going through each item with perhaps the use of a Results class. But I would like to learn how I could do this using Linq GroupBy() and maybe Distinct()?

I used GroupBy() to divide this into two lists based on Gender as follows.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person("Sam", 23, GenderType.M, "USA"),
        new Person("Jon", 13, GenderType.M, "USA"),
        new Person("Jen", 26, GenderType.F, "USA"),
        new Person("Thilini", 25, GenderType.F, "Sri Lanka"),
        new Person("Anna", 23, GenderType.F, "UK"),
        new Person("Chelsea", 35, GenderType.F, "UK"),
        new Person("Saman", 43, GenderType.M, "Sri Lanka"),
        new Person("Dan", 27, GenderType.M, "UK")
    };

    var maleList = people.GroupBy(x => x.Gender).Where(y => y.Key == GenderType.M);
    var femaleList = people.GroupBy(x => x.Gender).Where(y => y.Key == GenderType.F);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I don't understand how I would sub-divide each list now into many again based on Country.

Comment: _"I don't understand how I would sub-divide each list now into many again based on Country"_ -- why not? Just apply `GroupBy()` again, to each of your `maleList` and `femaleList` objects. What aren't you able to figure out?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I do know that in my list I have only two categories in Gender, so I can group by using a where like above. But I don't know in advance the countries I might have in my list, so what should I use to group by?

Comment: Can you clarify what is expected result? List of lists `List<List<Person>>`? Separate lists `List<Person>`? Or something else?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Either one would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know in advance the countries I might have in my list, so what should I use to group by?

The `GroupBy()` method doesn't care whether you know in advance what the possible values are. You can provide any equatable key, and it will produce an enumeration of groups on that key.

It sounds like what you need help with is not the grouping, but rather how to represent the result. There are lots of different ways you could do it, so the question is potentially too broad. But IMHO one of the most useful ways to store data that is grouped according to a key is in a dictionary. In your example, that would look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person("Sam", 23, GenderType.M, "USA"),
        new Person("Jon", 13, GenderType.M, "USA"),
        new Person("Jen", 26, GenderType.F, "USA"),
        new Person("Thilini", 25, GenderType.F, "Sri Lanka"),
        new Person("Anna", 23, GenderType.F, "UK"),
        new Person("Chelsea", 35, GenderType.F, "UK"),
        new Person("Saman", 43, GenderType.M, "Sri Lanka"),
        new Person("Dan", 27, GenderType.M, "UK")
    };

    Dictionary<GenderType, Dictionary<string, List<Person>>> groups =
        people.GroupBy(p => p.Gender).ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
            g1 => g1.GroupBy(p => p.Country).ToDictionary(g2 => g2.Key, g2 => g2.ToList()));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I.e. instead of having separate variables for each group, have a single dictionary where the key values are the gender, and the values are also dictionaries, which have as key values the country code. This will make it easy and quick to look up whatever combinations of gender and country you want.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is really what I was looking for - worked perfectly.

I like the idea of a dictionary and eliminating the separate variables.

Answer (score 5):

Simply do grouping by composite key:

```
var groups = people.GroupBy(p => new { p.Gender, p.Country });
```

Then you can iterate groups and display results:

```
foreach(var group in groups.OrderBy(g => g.Key.Gender).ThenBy(g => g.Key.Country))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key.Gender} sub list {group.Key.Country}");

    foreach(var person in group)
        Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} {person.Age} {person.Gender} {person.Country}");
}
```